# Relation between binomial and negative binomial

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

[image]

I was reading on negative binomial from a Statistics textbook and came across this portion on probability relation between binomial and negative binomial. $Y$ refers to the number of trials required to get $r$ successes.
Can somebody please explain the relation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on binomial distribution, event $\{X \geq r\}$ is the set of outcomes that satisfy "$n$ trials led to $r$ successes or more", which is equivalent to  "$r$-th success happened at $n$-th trial or before", which is in turn equivalent to "$n$ trials or less were required to get $r$ successes", and that is it.
$$\begin{align*}
P\{X \geq r\} &= P\{\mbox{at least r successes in n trials}\}\\
&= P\{\mbox{r-th success in n-th trial or before}\}\\
&= P\{\mbox{n or fewer trials to get r successes}\}\\
 &= P\{Y \leq n\}
\end{align*}$$

The second relation is the complement of first relation that is:
$$\begin{align*}
P\{X \geq r\} &= P\{Y \leq n\},\\
1 - P\{X \geq r\} &= 1 - P\{Y \leq n\},\\
P\{X < r\} &=  P\{Y > n\}\\
\end{align*}$$

The second relation means:

$$P\{\mbox{less than r successes in n trials}\}= P\{\mbox{more than n trials to get r successes}\}$$

Comment: Thank you. What about the second relation?

Comment: In the second relation, is it right to say that the P( less than r successes in n trials) $=$ P( more than n trials to get r successes)

Comment: (32) is simple the complement of (31)